# Range of representable values of 32-bit, 64-bit and 80-bit float IEEE-754?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, x86-64, ieee-754

In the C++ standard it says of floating literals:

> If the scaled value is not in the range of representable values for its type, the program is ill-formed.

The scaled value is the significant part multiplied by 10 ^ exponent part.

Under x86-64:

- `float` is a single-precision IEEE-754
- `double` is a double-precision IEEE-754
- `long double` is an 80-bit extended precision IEEE-754

In this context, what is the range of repsentable values for each of these three types?  Where is this documented? or how is it calculated?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Under x86-64, FP arithmetic is done with SSE, and therefore `long double` is 64 bits.

Comment: @MSalters: Can you clear this up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176290/long-double-confusion-on-x86-64-64bit

Comment: @MSalters: Cleared up now: Under the System V (Linux) x86-64 ABI, long double is 80 bits and implemented with the FPU (and not SSE).  On Windows `long double` is defined as 64-bit.  So it is different depending on the OS.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos it's depending on the compiler. GCC on Windows can also support 80-bit long double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (if you're on a machine with IEEE floating point) is
in `float.h`.  `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MAX` and `LDBL_MAX`.  On a system
with full IEEE support, something around 3.4e+38, 1.8E+308 and
1.2E4932.  (The exact values may vary, and may be expressed
differently, depending on how the compiler does its input and
rounding.  g++, for example, defines them to be compiler
built-ins.)

EDIT:

WRT your question (since neither I nor the other responders
actually answered it): the range of representable values is
`[-type_MAX...type]`, where
`type` is one of `FLT`, `DBL`, or `LDBL`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the number of exponent bits and mantissa bits, then based on the [IEEE-754 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary32), one can establish that the maximum absolute representable value is:

```
2^(2^(E-1)-1)) * (1 + (2^M-1)/2^M)
```

The minimum absolute value (not including zero or [denormals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal)) is:

```
2^(2-2^(E-1))
```

- For single-precision, `E` is 8, `M` is 23.
- For double-precision, `E` is 11, `M` is 52.
- For extended-precision, I'm not sure.  If you're referring to the 80-bit precision of the x87 FPU, then so far as I can tell, it's [not's IEEE-754 compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format)...

Comment: If `E` is a number of bits for the exponent, there is a `2^` missing in your formula, isn't there?

Comment: [Extended-precision types are fully compliant to IEEE-754](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67149953/995714) because the standard specifically specifies that and recommends the support of such types

Answer (score -4):

I was looking for largest representable number by 64 bits and ending up making my own 500 digit floating point calculator. This is what I come up with if all 64 bits are turned on

18,446,744,073,709,551,615

18 quintillion 446 quadrillion 744 trillion 73 billion 709 million 551 thousand 615

Comment: The question asked about floating point numbers. The answer you gave is for a 64-bit integer.