# sizeof long double and precision not matching?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, long-double

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    const long double ld = 0.12345678901234567890123456789012345L;
    printf("%lu %.36Lf\n", sizeof(ld), ld);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc 4.8.1` under `Ubuntu x64 13.04`, it prints:

```
16 0.123456789012345678901321800735590983
```

Which tells me that a long double weights 16 bytes but the decimals seems to be ok only to the 20th place. How is it possible? 16 bytes corresponds to a quad, and a quad would give me between 33 and 36 decimals.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176290/what-is-long-double-on-x86-64

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `long double` format in your C implementation uses an Intel format with a one-bit sign, a 15-bit exponent, and a 64-bit significand (ten bytes total). The compiler allocates 16 bytes for it, which is wasteful but useful for some things such as alignment. However, the 64 bits provide only log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>64</sup>) digits of significance, which is about 20 digits.

Comment: Is there a flag during gcc compilation to force long double = quad ?

Comment: @Vincent: Not that I am aware of. There is no hardware support for it, such using such a type would be slow. You can search for extended precision (fixed but longer than hardware support) or arbitrary precision (variable) for information on alternatives. They will be slow.

Comment: Small correction: The Intel 80-bit floating-point type uses 15 bits for the exponent and one bit for the sign, not 16 bits for the exponent.

Answer (score 4):

Various C implementations of the `long double` may have variant range and precision.  The `sizeof` hints to the underlying floating point notation, but does not specify it.  A `long double` is not required to have 33 to 36 decimals.  It could even have exactly the same representation as a `double`.

Without hard-coding the precision, but using all the available precision and not overdoing it, recommend:

```
const long double ld = 0.12345678901234567890123456789012345L;
printf("%.*Le\n", LDBL_DIG + 3, ld);
printf("%.*Le\n", LDBL_DIG + 3, nextafterl(ld, ld*2));
```

This prints out (on my eclipse intel 64-bit), of course, yours may differ.

```
1.234567890123456789013e-01
1.234567890123456789081e-01
```

[Edit]

On review, a +2 is sufficient.  Better to use `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.  see [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

```
printf("%.*Le\n", (LDBL_DIG + 3) - 1, ld);
printf("%.*Le\n", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, ld);
```

Answer (score 2):

The format on your computer is indeed the Intel double extended-precision format, 80 bits wide, with 15-bit exponent and 64-bit mantissa.

Only 10 consecutive bytes of the memory are actually used of the storage. Intel manuals ([Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual
Combined Volumes:
1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D and 4](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4)) say the following:

> When storing floating-point values in memory, half-precision values are stored in 2 consecutive bytes in memory;
>   single-precision values are stored in 4 consecutive bytes in memory; double-precision values are stored in 8
>   consecutive bytes; and double extended-precision values are stored in 10 consecutive bytes.

However, the x86 Linux ABIs specify that full 16 bytes are actually consumed. This is possibly because a 10-byte value could only have a fundamental alignment requirement of *2* in arrays, which can cause peculiar issues.

Also, array indexing is easier with multiples of 16.

Most of the time this is a non-issue, as `long double`s are usually used to minimize error in intermediate calculations and the result be then truncated to a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size *in bytes* of the data type. The floating point format types are not really comparable to the byte size of the data type, other that bigger size usually means better precision.