# pandas: a rolling window of hour-of-day average

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

related to: [daily data, resample every 3 days, calculate over trailing 5 days efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209520/daily-data-resample-every-3-days-calculate-over-trailing-5-days-efficiently) but the summing is over strided non-consecutive data.

I have an hourly time series. For every hour I would like to have the average of the same hour of the day, in the last preceding 10 days window. E.g. at 2019-08-14 23:00, I would like to have an average of all 23:00 data from 2019-08-04 till 2019-08-13.

Is there an efficient way to do so in pandas/numpy? Or should I roll my sleeves and write my own loops and data structures?

Extra points: if today is a workday (Mon-Fri), the average should be for the previous 10 workdays. If it's a weekend (Sat-Sun), for the previous 10 weekend-days (span about 2.5 months)

Comment: `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.hour).rolling(10).mean()`?

Comment: I would split in 2 df (workdays & weekend days) and then use Quang Hoang answer

Comment: wow - that simple... thanks guys, didn't realize that you can groupby and then roll