Python and C++ long double give different results
I'm trying to debug an inconsistency between a piece of C++ code and another piece of Python code which are returning different results.
In general, I have always expected floating point operations between the two environments to yield equal results, assuming the initial floating point values are the same. For example, if I perform a simple division between double values, like:
d1 = np.double(4e2)
d2 = np.double(4e4)
d3 = d1 / d2
------------
double x1 = 4e2;
double x2 = 4e4;
double x3 = x1 / x2;

the results are identical down to the individual bits:
Python:
4.0000000000000000000000000e+02
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01111001 01000000
4.0000000000000000000000000e+04
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10001000 11100011 01000000
1.0000000000000000208166817e-02
 01111011 00010100 10101110 01000111 11100001 01111010 10000100 00111111
-----------
Cpp:
4.00000000000000000000000e+02
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01111001 01000000 
4.00000000000000000000000e+04
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10001000 11100011 01000000 
1.00000000000000002081668e-02
01111011 00010100 10101110 01000111 11100001 01111010 10000100 00111111 

However, this seems not to happen when using np.longdouble and long double respectively. Not only do the initial values contain some randomly initialized bits (for both implementations, re-running results in the later part of the output bits to be somewhat randomly set...why?), but the resulting division yields consistently a different result:
d1 = np.longdouble(4e2)
d2 = np.longdouble(4e4)
d3 = d1 / d2
-----
4.0000000000000000000000000e+02
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000
 00000111 01000000 00110110 00100011 11111101 01111111 00000000 00000000
4.0000000000000000000000000e+04
 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 10011100
 00001110 01000000 00110110 00100011 11111101 01111111 00000000 00000000
1.0000000000000000208166817e-02
 00001010 11010111 10100011 01110000 00111101 00001010 11010111 10100011
 11111000 00111111 00110110 00100011 11111101 01111111 00000000 00000000

while for C++
long double x1 = 4e2l;
long double x2 = 4e4l;
long double x3 = x1 / x2;
------
4.00000000000000000000000e+02
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000 
00000111 01000000 01101010 10111110 11100000 01111111 00000000 00000000 
4.00000000000000000000000e+04
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 10011100 
00001110 01000000 01100111 10111110 11100000 01111111 00000000 00000000 
9.99999999999999999979671e-03
00001010 11010111 10100011 01110000 00111101 00001010 11010111 10100011 
11111000 00111111 01111000 10111110 11100000 01111111 00000000 00000000 

In my case, this has unfortunate repercussions due to calls to round which end up in different directions for the two implementations. So my question is, what exactly is going on? In what way is a long double special that the two results do not match?
In case it is relevant, here is how I output the corresponding binary representations:
def binar(num):
    num = np.array([num])
    s = ""
    ss = []
    count = 0
    for v in num.view(np.int8):
        s += " " + str(np.binary_repr(v, width=8))
        count += 1
        if count == 8:
            ss.append(s)
            s = ""
    if s != "":
        ss.append(s)
    return ss

and
void printBinary(const char* prefix, auto num)
{
    unsigned char* it = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&num);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(num); i+=8) {
        std::cout << prefix;
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            std::cout << std::bitset<8>(it[i+j]) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

EDIT: As requested, here are the values for both Python and C++ printed using printf("%La") (for Python I used Pybind11 to pass the long double along):
Python:
d1 = 0xc.8p+5
d2 = 0x9.c4p+12
d3 = 0xa.3d70a3d70a3d8p-10
----------
C++
x1 = 0xc.8p+5
x2 = 0x9.c4p+12
x3 = 0xa.3d70a3d70a3d70ap-10


OT: In the C++ code, what happens if the size of num is not a multiple of 8?

"Not only do the initial values contain some randomly initialized bits (for both implementations, re-running results in the later part of the output bits to be somewhat randomly set...why?)" That's part of what long doubles are. "but the resulting division yields consistently a different result:" - well, yes; you started with "some randomly initialized bits" in the least-significant places; garbage in, garbage out.

Just because a type has the same name in two different programming languages, you cannot assume their implementation, precision, rounding behaviour or other semantics to be identical.

@Someprogrammerdude In my case, long double is 16 for both C++ and Python, and since this is debugging code, it doesn't matter.

@JesperJuhl Except I can inspect them, and indeed both have 16 bytes. In addition, numpy specifically specifies that np.longdouble is essentially long double, and so the underlying implementation should match: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html

@KarlKnechtel What do you mean with "that's part of what long doubles are"? Also, how is my code "garbage in". I am explicitly initializing values, so I do not see where garbage can come in. In addition, while the bit representations might differ, the printed values never change, which suggests to me that those bits are not really important for the values at hand.

@Svalorzen Using your binar function, I am only getting 8 bytes of representation.

@matszwecja On my machine, np.longdouble(0).nbytes returns 16. If on your machine this is 8, then you'll only get 8 bytes out (you can see how I also get 8 bytes out in the initial example when I'm using standard Python doubles).

Are you sure code for converting to binary representation is correct? It doesn't look like correct IEEE 754 representation, honestly, with those 7 empty bytes at the beggining.

@matszwecja For C++, I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199121/1356926. For Python, I tried different approaches, and this one gives an exact bit-by-bit match for numbers that have more significant digits (say 1.0/7.0), so I assumed it was good enough.

I mean that you can't rely on long double being a specific sized type that's larger than 64 bits; and that the literals you use to initialize those values (at least in Python) are still of an ordinary double type and only carry 64 bits of precision - if you then assign them to a wider type, you can't always get consistent results. That might not be possible anyway, actually.

By the way, even if your long double happen to be 16 bytes wide, it's not necessarily using all the 128 bits of that. It might just be 80 bits, or less, or more.

If you're on an x86_64 target you're probably using 80-bit long doubles (despite sizeof(long double) being 16). Don't confuse how many bytes of memory an object takes up with how many bits are used to represent a value.

@KarlKnechtel While I agree that I can't rely on that in general, I'm trying to debug my issue on my specific machine, so I am expecting its behavior to be at least consistent with itself. I really do not understand your point about the precision; when you initialize a double using a float, it's not like the result is randomly initialized because float has fewer bits. The result is deterministically upcast, and while the result might not compare equal to the original float one, it will still consistently initialize the same over multiple runs. Why would that not be the case for long doubles?

@StephenM.Webb Yeah, that's what I was guessing due to some of the bits being randomly initialized. Still numpy's implementation is in C, and for any given machine, shoudn't the underlying types behave the same? Or does somehow Python's division with long doubles end up using different assembly instructions that what C++ uses? That would sound really strange to me.

@Svalorzen "what exactly is going on?" --> Consider posting the C++ values with C like code printf("%La\n", (long double) x3); to see the exact value without printing unused bytes that printBinary() may print.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I have added the printed values for both Python and C++; as you can see the initial two values are identical, but the third differs.

The C++ appears as correctly rounded to me (round to nearest, tie to even mode), assuming a 64bits significand (80 bit extended precision floating point). numpy result appear as correctly rounded in double precision (53 bits significand). Could it be that long double array division is not implemented (fallback to double precision division) ?

@Svalorzen Appears your C++ long double is 80-bit and Python double is 64-bit.  I do not trust your binary dump code.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I mean, my binary dump code is only part of it, numpy itself specifies that longdouble takes 16 bytes, while double is 8. How would you verify whether that type is really 64 bits? I tried even compiling using C, and the result is still the same as C++.

@aka.nice I have verified thanks to the posted answer that indeed a function called LONGDOUBLE_divide is being called (and only if np.longdouble types are being used, if I use np.double it is not called), so it does make sense that it is at least treating the type appropriately. How can I check whether it is indeed 64 bit? Any other test operation I might do to see what the output is?

@Svalorzen "longdouble takes 16 bytes," is more likely long double is 10 bytes of info and 6 bytes of (garbage) padding.  Rather than x1 / x2, let us first clearly look at assignment like double x1 = 0.1; and double d1 = 0.1L; (assign with a non-exact value) and then see what those print using "%a" like code.

Check what instructions numpy is using for your particular installation (see below).
On my particular machine, I am unable to reproduce your differences. I always get your "C++" results with C++ (using godbolt), with a pip-installed copy of Numpy (on my machine), and with a compiled-from-scratch version of Numpy (on my machine).
For testing C++, I used godbolt. I get the same results with the latest release of clang, gcc, and icc supported there.

URL: https://godbolt.org/z/bhPo9M43c
Key instruction used: FDIVP (an x87 instruction)

For Python, I tried both the pip-installed version and compiling from scratch myself. I ran the following cells in Jupyter, with Cython (since that was easier for me than using pybind11).
# ---- CELL 1 ----------------
%load_ext Cython

# ---- CELL 2 ----------------
%%cython
# distutils: define_macros=NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
import cython
from libc.stdio cimport snprintf

def to_str(cnp.ndarray x):
    cdef char buf[256]
    cdef long double v = (<long double *>x.data)[0]
    snprintf(buf, 256, "%0.20Le    %0.16La\n", v, v)
    return bytes(buf).decode('ascii')
    
# ---- CELL 3 ----------------
d1 = np.longdouble(4e2)
d2 = np.longdouble(4e4)
d3 = d1 / d2
print(to_str(np.asarray(d3)))

And the output was equivalent to your "C++" result.
9.99999999999999999980e-03    0xa.3d70a3d70a3d70a0p-10

The key instruction used by numpy is FDIVRP (another x87 instruction that just handles the stack slightly differently from FDIVP).
objdump -d ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep -A50 '<LONGDOUBLE_divide>:'
00000000000e55b0 <LONGDOUBLE_divide>:
...snip...
   e55ee:       de f9                   fdivrp %st,%st(1)
...snip...

Try running objdump on your particular numpy library and see if it was compiled differently.

Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it seems that both my C++ and Python dumps contain the fdivrp instruction. I've also confirmed that LONGDOUBLE_divide is indeed the function that is being called in Python using gdb and setting a breakpoint on it, although I can't manage to dig deeper as there are no symbols available to print. This is really strange..

Interesting. Perhaps you can set a breakpoint at the fdivrp instruction using a C++ debugger and precisely check the inputs and outputs.

Then might the conversion long double -> double happen upon return to the interpreter ?
